# GeoJSON: Are Properties allowed in FeatureCollection?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I could not find any relevant information in the spec: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

Is it allowed to have a `properties` key in a `FeatureCollection`? Or is it only possible for Features?

If it's possible, how can I access the properties within `openlayers`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

The specification does not forbid it explicitly, but feature collections do not have properties. GeoJSON spec only mentions the following keys for FeatureCollection:

- `type` - must be `FeatureCollection
- `features` - array of feaures
- `bbox` - bounding box of the whole feature collection

As I see from OpenLayers code, `properties` is only processed for feature instances, not for the feature collection.

Comment: Is it still the case in 2021?

Comment: same challenge for me, can we add properties?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25279/is-it-valid-to-have-a-properties-element-in-an-geojson-featurecollection To the two above me - read the answer here and the comments.

Answer (score -2):

Switch to Leaflet is easier and it accepts GeoJSON with FeatureCollection. You can get attributes of the in the Popup as well when you click the objects.

However, Openlayers do as well access FeatureCollection. Mobile (jQuery Mobile) example for Openlayers demonstrated accessing properties.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-jq.html#mappage

Click the black icons and you will see the popup form with these attributes.

This is part of the GeoJSON in the mobile example.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", 
          "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [1332700, 7906300]},
          "properties": {"Name": "Igor Tihonov","Country":"Sweden", "City":"Gothenburg"}
        },
        { "type": "Feature", 
          "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [790300, 6573900]},
          "properties": {"Name": "Marc Jansen","Country":"Germany", "City":"Bonn"}
        },
        { "type": "Feature", 
          "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [568600, 6817300]},
          "properties": {"Name": "Bart van den Eijnden","Country":"Netherlands", "City":"Utrecht"}
        },
        { "type": "Feature", 
          "geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-7909900, 5215100]}
        }
    ]
}
```